# 8 чекбосов или 256 вариантов?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, checkbox, логика, response

На клиенте (index.jsp) имею 8 чекбоксов - комплектации авто:

> 1. Кожаный салон,
> 2. Цвет металлик,
> 3. ГУР,
> 4. Спойлер,
> 5. Подогрев сидений,
> 6. Подогрев задних сидений
> 7. Климат контроль,
> 8. 3-ех зонный климат контроль

JavaScript методом `XMLHttpRequest` передаю серверу значение всех чекнутых и не чекнутых боксов. Например, все восемь будут выглядеть так: 111111,11. Отмеченный первый: 0,01, второй: 0.1, первый и пятый: 100,01, шестой и первый 1000,01 и т.д.

Бизнес под каждый результат готовит соответствующий запрос в БД и возвращает клиенту ответ.

С математикой у меня не все радужно, и по моим расчетам выходит, что у меня 256 вариантов комплектации авто. То есть мне необходимо написать под каждый вариант соответствующих запросов в размере 256? Но это вообще не вариант.

Смотрела готовый вариант [оракла](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox), но там перебор картинок и, думаю, результаты БД вшить не получится.

**Ребят, вопрос подразумевала в следующем: как в сервлете обработать 256 запросов клиента. С учетом, что каждый запрос обращение к БД.**

Comment: Если это именно восемь чекбоксов, то вариантов всего 2**8=256 - школьная информатика)

Comment: Но что-то я несколько раз перечитал и так и не понял, в чём вопрос-то и решение чего именно нужно

Comment: насколько я Вас понял - вам просто нужен динамически формируемый запрос в зависимости от переменных

Comment: Вопрос в том как построить запрос? Тогда нужно расписать поподробнее структуру БД и добавить метку Oracle.

Comment: Если посмотреть на математику выбора под другим углом, то: у вас 8 значений, каждое из которых равно 0 или 1. "0 или 1" - это как бит, а 8 битов (1 байт) - это 256 значений

Comment: Зачем под каждую комбинацию делать свой запрос? Вероятно, это всё заменяется одним запросом с использованием динамически формируемого `IN()` (или его аналогом).

Comment: *Например, все восемь будут выглядеть так: 111111,11.* Битовая маска (SET) покрасивше будет... да и разбирать потом проще. *это всё заменяется одним запросом с использованием динамически формируемого IN() (или его аналогом).* Зачем тут динамика-то? тупое через AND собранное `(car.option_N_field = TRUE) OR (checkbox_N = 0)` - ну или около того, в зависимости от логики работы фильтра.

Comment: @Akina не знаю, мне первое что пришло в голову - `type IN ('Кожаный салон', 'ГУР', 'Климат контроль')`. Так сказать, "выбираем только то, что выбрано".

Comment: @Regent Вы закладываетесь на неизвестную нам структуру хранения данных... и показанное условие отбора предполагает одну из наименее вероятных структур, если речь идёт о более-менее реальной системе.

Comment: Исправила на 256)

Comment: Для восьми чекбоксов достаточно одного байта. Зачем у вас запятая в числе?  И какую задачу вообще решаем? Как построить запрос из восьми опций? Как его обработать на другом конце?

Comment: "как ... обработать 256 запросов клиента" ??! - запрос один и тот же. Данные - разные. Зачем у Вас запятая в значениях?

Comment: @Эникейщик, согласна, запятая не нужна, курю битовую маску Akina, Вопрос уточнила в теле, запрос из восьми опций по аналогии с ответом dmitryshishkin, вот как его обработать на другом конце в этом проблема.

Comment: @Igor, хорошо запрос один и тот же, как тогда данные менять исходя из вариантов боксов? С запятой разбираюсь.

Comment: @VikaSmirnova Добавьте Ваш html/js в вопрос.

Comment: @Igor убрала теги

Comment: Покажите пример ответа на запрос и скажите что вы с этим ответом хотите сделать

Comment: можете пожалуйста уточнить постановку вопроса: 1) что задано/фиксировано, что можно менять? (модель данных, интерфейс к "бизнесу", реализация, итд) 2) содержание чекбоксов действительно независимо и корреляции здесь случайны (5 включает 6, 7 включает 8)? 3) расшифруйте "256 запросов", возможно вы имеете ввиду 256 вариантов запроса?

Comment: @Ramiz Постараюсь объяснить исходя из того как я вас поняла своими словами, я не программист. 
1) имеется стандартный проект Model, View и Controller. JSP, Сервлет, DAO class с прописанным бизнесом взаимодействия с БД, отдельно геттеры сеттеры. Стандартная БД MySql с таблицей моделей авто (Skoda Rapid, Octavia, Yeti, Superb) и полями id, name, type + 8-мью комплектациями (8 checkbox).Клинту на входе показывается базовая комплектация авто и наши 8 checkbox.

Comment: Клинт подтверждает свой выбор с определенными опциями к примеру 2,5,7 и в БД заноситься резерв авто с выбранными опциями. 
Моя загвоздка в запросах в БД по чекнутым checkbox. К настоящему моменту задумалась, о цикле в запросе по каждому клику на checkbox.  

2) касательно checkbox, корреляционной зависимости между ними нет, произвольно включаю/выключаю любой из боксов. 
3) да, имела ввиду 256 вариантов запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что правильно все понял, но постарался решить вашу задачу.

```js
// Список инпутов
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);

// Конейтнер, куда выплевываем результат
const resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');

// Событие на переключение чекбоксов
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', getResponseString);
});

function getResponseString() {
  var result = '';
  
  // Собираем строку с правильными значениями
  inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
    result += input.checked ? '1' : 0;
    
    // Добавляем точку
    if(i === 5) result += '.';
  });
  
  result = result.split('.');
  
  // Получаем левую часть
  let left = result[0].split('').reduce(function(prev, current) {
    // Откидываем нули в начале  
    return !prev && !parseInt(current) ? prev : prev + current;
  }, '');
  
  // Если вообще всё отсеяли, то делаем нулем
  if(left == '') left = '0';
  
  // Правая часть
  let right = result[1].split('').reduceRight(function(prev, current) {
    // Откидываем нули в начале  
    return !prev && !parseInt(current) ? prev : prev + current;
  }, '');
 
  // Переменная в которую склеим запрос
  var request = '';
  
  // Если в правой части есть хоть что-то, то склеиваем
  if(right != '') {
    // Разворачиваем правую часть, это важно потому что мы собирали првую часть с помощью reduceRight, а она идет по строке в обратном порядке
    right = right.split('').reverse().join('');
    
    // и склевивем
    request = left + '.' + right;
  }
  
  // в противном случае отдаем только левую часть
  else {
    request = left;
  }
  
  // Выводим результат
  resultContainer.textContent = request;
}

// Взываем при загрузке, чтобы сразу же видеть результат
getResponseString();
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Кожаный салон</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Цвет металлик</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>ГУР</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Спойлер</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Подогрев сидений</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Подогрев задних сидений</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Климат контроль</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>3-ех зонный климат контроль</span>
</label><br><br>

<div id="result">000000,00</div>
```

Comment: Я вот когда написал понял, что вам вероятно нужно решение на Java. Если так, то грустненько и тег `javascript` ни к месту.

Comment: примерно тоже самое я имею на клиенте, теперь сервер должен обработать 256 запросов к БД, здесь я застопарилась.

Comment: уберите теги `javascript` и `html`, пожалуйста :-) Ваша задача не про это.